# Why does my Rokinon lens have no aperture control on my screen?

Tags: aperture, samyang

[image][image]

Hello..  I am a beginner photographer,  I'm shooting with a Nikon D5500. I just purchased a Rokinon ( lens)24mm T1.5 ED AS IF UMC (for Cinema) so I noticed that I can't change the aperture on my camera. The f stops show  something like this f--

Any suggestions why this is happening?  I have no problem with the aperture on my kit lens which is the Nikon DX
AF-P NIKKOR 70-300mm

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Samyang/Rokinon lenses are "manual only". They do not perform any electronic communication with the body, so the camera cannot control the aperture of the lens. You must use the aperture ring on the lens itself to adjust the aperture; just as you must use the focus ring on the lens to focus. You will not have wide-open metering (so the metering on D3x00 and D5x00 bodies will be inaccurate, as they don't do stop-down metering) again, because the body can't tell the lens to be wide open during composition and only stop down during the exposure. You will not have lens EXIF information (focal length, aperture used, lens name, etc.)

This is why Samyang (aka Rokinon, Bower, Pro-Optic, Vivitar, Phoenix, etc. etc.) lenses are so cheap.

Comment: I don't believe this is entirely true. My Samyang 24mm is absolutely a manual-only lens, but I set the aperture ring to its smallest size (largest f-stop value), and my Nikon body controls the aperture. The aperture setting is reported back to the camera.

Comment: @scottbb, I'm a Canon shooter. :)  I'm not that familiar with how Nikon bodies deal with non-CPU lenses.

Comment: I'm a Nikon shooter, but I forgot the distinction between D3xxx/D5xxx bodies vs higher-end when it comes to non-CPU lenses. Minor quibble: I wouldn't say _Samyang/Rokinon lenses are "manual only"_, because some (such as my 24mm f/1.4) are definitely CPU. But granted, their cine lenses, such as OP's, are non-CPU.

Answer (score 0):

From Nikon's help page, [What does the FEE or F-- error message displayed on an SLR camera mean?](https://www.nikonimgsupport.com/ni/NI_article?articleNo=000001426&configured=1&lang=en_US)

> **The F-- error message is indicating the camera and lens are not communicating**. Either the lens is not designed with electronic contacts, or maybe the lens is not connected fully and clicked in to place. Make sure if the lens is a CPU lens, that it is completely connected onto the cameras bayonet lens mount. Also, be careful not to press the lens release button as this may cause the error. Rotate the lens to lock in place.
>
> You will hear a "click" when the lens is locked in place.
>
> If the problem only occurs occasionally and intermittently, the lens pins and/ or camera contacts may be dirty. Inspect the lens contacts for grease or dirt and wipe them clean with a lint free cloth.